Given $Q\in O(d)$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ with $n<d$, there exists $S\in SO(d)$ such that $QX=SX$

We say that $f:\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $O(d)$ or $SO(d)$ invariant if for all $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ with $X=QY$ for some $Q\in O(d)$ or $Q\in SO(d)$ then $f(X)=f(Y)$.

Where $O(d)=\{Q\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}\mid Q^TQ=I\}$ and $SO(d)=\{S\in O(d)\mid \det(S)=1\}$. Assume $n<d$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $SO(d)$ invariant. I want to show that it is $O(d)$ invariant. To prove that, I want to show that given $Q\in O(d)$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ we can find $S\in SO(d)$ such that $QX=SX$. Knowing that, given $X,Y$ with $X=QY$ for some $Q\in O(d)$ we have
$$
f(X)=f(QY)=f(SY)=f(Y)
$$
I have some intuition that $n<d$ gives us the "freedom" with the rotation but I don't know how to show it formally.

If $n>0$ the conjecture of your title didn't hold (but you modified your question after I began to answer, which is not recommended), because if $(Q-S)X=0$ for all $X\in\Bbb R^{d\times n}$ then $(Q-S)Z=0$ for all $Z\in\Bbb R^{d\times1}$, i.e. $Q-S=0$.
However, it is true (and sufficient for your goal) that given $X\in\Bbb R^{d\times n}$ and $Q\in O(d)\setminus SO(d)$, there exists $S\in SO(d)$ (depending on $Q$ but also on $X$) such that $QX=SX$: let $S$ act exactly like $Q$ on some hyperplane $H\supseteq\operatorname{im}X$, and act on $H^\perp$ like $-Q$.

Thank you, I've edited my question.
